# I have problem to add new object to store React redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have problem when i want add new object to store shows up to me error : Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, parts}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. When i not add object only the value of everything works

My code reducer:

```
const initialState = [

]
   

const newTrainingReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_EXERCISE':
            return [...state,number]
        default: {
            return state;
    }
    }
};

export default newTrainingReducer;
```

action:

```
export const addTraining = (number) => ({
  type: 'ADD_EXERCISE',
  payload: number
});
```

function call:

```
const AddItem = (index) => {
        const test = {
          name: index, parts: []
        }

        dispatch(addTraining(test));
        
        
    
  };
```

[warning operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIDvQ.png)

[example add only value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvqNo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have `number` available in reducer, you need to put `action.payload`

```
const initialState = [

]
   

const newTrainingReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_EXERCISE':
            return [...state, action.payload]
        default: {
            return state;
    }
    }
};

export default newTrainingReducer;
```

Comment: I reapair this code and have same error. I think that i used wrong way spread operator in example

Comment: @AlbertDąbal that's happening in your render/return function, please share the code.

Comment: Do you mean the component where is the code calling?

Comment: `return()` function